# Which button is better when you want to load results from a filter?

Tags: gui-design, buttons

I am redesigning an application and, one of our tasks is to redesign the UI and clarify/connect UI with the action intended.
I noticed we are using different buttons for the same target action which is basically:

1 - Get results on a screen by submitting a button (after you choose which filters you want on).

Which option would be more user friendly and why and what are the advantages and main differences in-between these buttons?

Nowadays, on the web age, people got used to the same function applied to software and web applications. Would simply "Search" be the best option?

[image: Search]

[image: update]

[image: go]

[image: reload]

[image: apply]

[image: Load Results]

Answer (score 2):

Let' take them one by one and analyze the rationale behind each button label. Keep in mind that they need to be short, clear and inform the user exactly what is going to happen:

**Search** - most common search button label and a safe option to use in this situation.

**Update** - Less common and not advisable in my experience. Update button is mostly used when changing a setting or when editing a shopping cart.

**Go** - Go where? Nope.

**Reload** - Confusing.. Reloading the page? Reloading the search filters?

**Apply** - This is the one I would go with. You are basically applying the filters to the results list. I would even go with **Apply filters**.

**Load Results** -  From my experience, I haven't seen this label in a while. It sounds antiquated and not UX friendly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not loaded results, then I would go with “Search”. If you have loaded results I would use “Apply Filter”. Users will get confused with some of the other options.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the feedback. I appreciate it. I am still trying to understand the origins. How did we users learn to associate this action with these buttons? I am trying to get some ground biography on this and understand why.